# Search algorithms or tool for searching from database

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I have this database table:

```
Column       Type

source       text            
news_id      int(12)             
heading      text            
body         text        
source_url   tinytext
time         timestamp
news_pic     char(100) 
location     char(128)
tags         text
time_created timestamp
hits         int(10)
```

Now I was searching for an algorithm or tool to perform a search for a keyword in this table which contains news data. Keyword should be searched in heading,body,tags and number of hits on the news to give best results.

Comment: There are php script all over the net to establish connection to database, request it and fetch result...if it's mysql database, a tool like phpmyadmin would do the job...

Answer (score 3):

MySQL already has the tool you need built-in: full-text search. I'm going to assume you know how to interact with MySQL using PHP. If not, look into that first. Anyway ...

1) Add full-text indexes to the fields you want to search:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME add fulltext(heading);
alter table TABLE_NAME add fulltext(body);
alter table TABLE_NAME add fulltext(tags);
```

2) Use a `match ... against` statement to perform a full-text search:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where match(heading, body, tags, hits) against ('SEARCH_STRING');
```

Obviously, substitute your table's name for TABLE_NAME and your search string for SEARCH_STRING in these examples.

I don't see why you'd want to search the number of hits, as it's just an integer. You could *sort* by number of hits, however, by adding an `order` clause to your query:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where match(heading, body, tags, hits) against ('SEARCH_STRING') order by hits desc;
```

Comment: What I need is an algorithm like 'Slope One',which is used for suggesting user some stuff.In my search results I want to give priority to some fields like headings, tags, and number of hits that news had, this cannot be done using simple MySQL queries